# plotting multiple time series, with single date series and with py_date()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a matplotlib plot with dates on the X axis. I have managed to plot a single time series using [py_date](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date).

However, I want to plot more than a single time series for the same set of dates. My data looks something like this:

```
Date (X)     Y1      Y2
20010101     101    99.2
20010102     123    45.2
20010103     104    99.0
20010104     100    99.5
20010105     167    87.6
```

How may I create a plot with multiple Y values (2 in this case), spanning over the same date range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just plot them separately:

```
plot_date(dates, y1)
plot_date(dates, y2)
```

Comment: Thanks!. BTW, is there a way to plot the second series with a different color (so I can tell Y1 and Y2 apart?)

Comment: Yeah, most matplotlib methods accept a number of common keyword arguments (`kwargs`) for customization. `plot_date` accepts, for example, `marker` and `color`. Have a look in the [documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date).